# Why am I having difficulty making execvp in C work?

Tags: c

I need to implement a basic shell in C.
One of things I need is to implement a function that has a command and to execute it.
my code:

```
    pID=fork();

    if (pID == 0)
       execvp(tmp[0], tmp);
    else if (pID > 0)
    {
       printf("%d", pID);
       wait(NULL);
    }
    else
      printf("Failed to create proccess \n");
```

The problem is that no matter what is the command I put in tmp, the program shows me the prompt again, and do nothing except that.
For example if I write `gedit` (in order to open the `gedit` — a ntpad of Ubuntu), it doesn't open it, or if write `ls -a` it doesn't show me any output as the terminal of Ubuntu does.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your initialization of tmp

Comment: You need to show the code that sets up `tmp`

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to show us how you populate `tmp`?

Comment: You may also want to check error value of `execvp` in case it returns and do something about it.

Comment: execvp in C does work. What doesn't work is your invocation of it. Some possibilities: $PATH isn't set properly, or your tmp array isn't terminated with NULL. P.S. It's "ubunt*u*"

Answer (score 2):

execvp should work.  As the others mentioned, you really need to show how you populate tmp.  That said, I would guess that that's where the error is.  tmp needs to be a null terminated array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
int    pid = fork;
char * tmp[2];
  memset( tmp, 0, sizeof(tmp) );
  tmp[0] = argv[0];
  if( 0 == pid )
  {
    if( -1 == execvp( tmp[0], tmp ) )
    {
      char errmsg[64];
      snprintf( errmsg, sizeof(errmsg), "exec '%s' failed", tmp[0] );
      perror( errmsg );
    }
  else if( 0 < pid )
  {
    printf("[%d] %s\n", pid, tmp[0]);
    wait(NULL);
  }
  else
  {
    perror("fork failed");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you've failed to tell us what you're passing through the `tmp` variable to `execvp`, my psychic sense tells me that you forgot to null-terminate your argument list.  A NULL argument tells `execvp` where the last argument is, and if you fail to put in a NULL, it will start reading random garbage off the stack.

If that random garbage points to large strings of non-zero data, it will run out of space to store the supposed arguments to the new process, which is typically a few hundred KB (see [this page](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) for some system-specific numbers, as well as various ways of getting your system's maximum arguments size).

When there's too much argument data, the system call [`execve(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) (called internally by `execvp`) fails with the error `E2BIG`.

So to see if this is what's happening to you, check the return value from `execvp`.  If it even returns at all, it failed (if it succeeded, it wouldn't have returned since a new process would be executing!), so check the global value of `errno` to see why it failed:

```
if (pID == 0)
{
    execvp(tmp[0], tmp);
    printf("exec failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

execvp() requires full path . If in tmp[0] isnt the full path of your executable file use execv()

```
execv(tmp[0], tmp);
```